# Open Edit Form on selected item edit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angular, typescript

i have a list of data. each list row has edit button to edit record of that specific row. on that edit button click i want to open an edit for under that specific row to update record. i applied ngFor on list and ngIf on div but it is not working properly my html code

**My HTML CODE**

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let album of calls | async ; index as i">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a style="border:1px solid red">{{album.id}}</a>
{{i}}
        <a  style="border:1px solid black">{{album.title}}</a>
        <button (click)="onClick(album)">Edit Click</button>
        <form *ngIf="subdiv">
            <a  style="border:1px solid black">{{album.title}}</a>
 <button (click)="onEdit(album)">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**My TS Code**

```
onClick(user: any) {
  this.subdiv= true
  console.log(user);
}
```

Problem is when ever i click on any list item edit button all list items forms show at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead, set the id of the album to being edited. This will make only one item to be edited a time.

**HTML**

```
<form *ngIf="subdiv === album.id">
            <a  style="border:1px solid black">{{album.title}}</a>
 <button (click)="onEdit(album)">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

**TS**

```
onClick(album: any) {
  this.subdiv= album.id;
}
```

I would also change the name of the variable as well to something like 'currentEditAlbumId`.

**Another solution**

Change the `album` model to include another property:

**Album.ts**

```
export class Album {
 id: number;
 title: string;
 edit: boolean;
}
```

Then the same solution uses this `edit` variable.

**HTML**

```
<form *ngIf="album.edit">
            <a  style="border:1px solid black">{{album.title}}</a>
 <button (click)="onEdit(album)">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

**TS**

```
onClick(album: any) {
  album.edit = true;
}
```

This solution will make it editable for multiple items. Thanks [@pc_coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2576254/pc-coder) for pointing out the first solution will not work for simultaneous edit.

Comment: and how to close this ngif div on same button click? like toggle? @Manish

Comment: on onclick function?

Comment: Yes, as that is what is called again on click of the Edit button.

Answer (score 1):

because subdiv is general so if you make it true ,all elements will be editable.

you should put `subdiv` variable inside `album` model.

```
onClick(user: any) {
  user.subdiv= true
}
onCancel(user: any) {
  user.subdiv= false
}
```

in html

```
<div class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let album of calls | async ; index as i">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a style="border:1px solid red">{{album.id}}</a>
{{i}}
        <a  style="border:1px solid black">{{album.title}}</a>
        <button *ngIf="!album.subdiv" (click)="onClick(album)">Edit Click</button>
        <button *ngIf="album.subdiv"  (click)="onCancel(album)">Cancel Click</button>
        <form *ngIf="album.subdiv">
            <a  style="border:1px solid black">{{album.title}}</a>
 <button (click)="onEdit(album)">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: and how to close this ngif div on same button click? like toggle?

Comment: Just make album.subdiv false in onEdit function

Comment: And also put one more button to to show with if condition to cancel edit if false show edit button if true show cancel button. Check edited answer